# Import fenics, no module "fenics" found on python3.6.10

Tags: fenics, pymesh

I needed python 3.6.10 for Pymesh2 which i hadn't installed yet. But I am trying to get Fenics to work in this version of python so it can be used concurrently with Pymesh2.

I followed this installation: https://fenicsproject.org/download/archive/

But import fenics doens't work in python console.

Created an new environment with python 3.6.10, but my base environment is the latest version.

Using this link (https://fenicsproject.org/download/archive/), installed fenics on the virtual environment.

it didn't work.

> > > import fenics
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fenics'

restarted WSL too, didn't work.